# Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

We currently have an application in Microsoft Access that has some forms connected to tools. We now need to change it so that the application is powered from a Microsoft SQL Server database instead of Microsoft Access.

Is it possible to connect the Access Application to the SQL Server so that the forms continue working the way they do, but update data in the SQL Server database only, and there is no longer any Access database?

Comment: Have you looked at creating linked tables?

Comment: Hi! Haven't yet, but I'm going to follow the tutorials Johnny Bones linked to, and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this eaily by following these steps:

1. Set up an ODBC link to your SQL database.

There is an excellent step-by-step tutorial [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1470/microsoft-access-and-sql-server-integration/) on setting this up.

2. Import your Access tables into SQL Server using the Import Wizard

There is an excellent step-by-step tutorial [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/SQLServerUpsizing/importing/Import_Access_DB.asp) for using the wizard.

3. Set up linked tables that point to the SQL Server

Microsoft provides [instructions for doing this](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-SQL-Server-data-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e?CorrelationId=61074654-e633-4fc5-9430-8646cfdcb14b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bm2).  Just remember that SQL tables **must** have Primary Keys assigned, or the data will not be updateable in Access.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to try this out as soon as I get a SQL Server up and running.

Comment: Hi Johnny, I went through these guides and tutorials to migrate my own VB.NET project form Access to SQL Server, but whenever I run my project and attempt to insert new records, this only gets inserted into the Access database, and not the SQL Server table... Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Your tables aren't linked.  If you link them properly, it won't be written to Access at all, it'll be written directly to SQL Server.